# WordPress Widget is not saving new instance

Tags: wordpress, instance, widget, product, savechanges

I have a very strange issue with the wordpress widget. I am editing an existed wordpress widget form Phomedia theme, and I am trying to add one more instance so I can use it to filter posts. In the code it is $instance['custom']. But everytime I hit save the value is dissapearing. I got really stuck with it for several, trying to figure out what is going wrong, but couldn't find it. Here is the code

```
        class MZ_Widget_Latest_Products extends WP_Widget {

            /**
             * Widget Constuctor
             */
            function MZ_Widget_Latest_Products() {
                $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_mz_wpsc_latest_products','description' => __( 'Phomedia Latest Products Widget', 'wpsc' ) );
                $this->WP_Widget( 'wpsc_latest_products', __( 'Phomedia Latest Products', 'wpsc' ), $widget_ops );
            }

            /**
             * Widget Output
             *
             * @param $args (array)
             * @param $instance (array) Widget values.
             */
            function widget( $args, $instance ) {

                global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

                extract( $args );

                $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? __( 'Latest Products', 'wpsc' ) : $instance['title'] );

                echo $before_widget;


                if ( $title )
                    echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
                wpsc_phomedia_latest_product( $args, $instance );
                echo $after_widget;
            }

            /**
             * Update Widget
             *
             * @param $new_instance (array) New widget values.
             * @param $old_instance (array) Old widget values.
             *
             * @return (array) New values.
             */
            function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

                $instance = $old_instance;
                $instance['title']      = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
                $instance['number']     = (int)$new_instance['number'];
                $instance['image']      = (bool)$new_instance['image'];
                $instance['height']     = (int)$new_instance['height'];
                $instance['width']      = (int)$new_instance['width'];
                $instance['custom']     = $instance['custom'];

                return $instance;

            }

            /**
             * Widget Options Form
             *
             * @param $instance (array) Widget values.
             */
            function form( $instance ) {

                global $wpdb;

                // Defaults
                $instance = wp_parse_args( (array)$instance, array(
                    'title' => '',
                    'number' => 4,
                    'width' => 173,
                    'height' => 151
                ) );

                // Values
                $title    = esc_attr( $instance['title'] );
                $number   = (int)$instance['number'];
                $image    = (bool)$instance['image'];
                $width    = (int) $instance['width'];
                $height   = (int) $instance['height']; 
                $custom = $instance['custom']; ?>

                <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('custom'); ?>">Custom: <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('custom'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('custom'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($custom); ?>" /></label></p>
                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:', 'wpsc' ); ?></label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of products to show:', 'wpsc' ); ?></label>
                    <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'image' ); ?>"<?php checked($image); ?> onclick="jQuery('.wpsc_latest_image').toggle()">
                    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'image' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Show Thumbnails', 'wpsc' ); ?></label>
                </p>

                <div class="wpsc_latest_image"<?php if( !checked( $image ) ) { echo ' style="display:none;"'; } ?>>
                    <p>
                        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('width'); ?>"><?php _e('Width:', 'wpsc'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('width'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('width'); ?>" value="<?php echo $width ; ?>" size="3" />
                        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('height'); ?>"><?php _e('Height:', 'wpsc'); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('height'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('height'); ?>" value="<?php echo $height ; ?>" size="3" />
                    </p>
                </div>
        <?php
            }
        }

        add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget("MZ_Widget_Latest_Products");' ) );

        function wpsc_phomedia_latest_product( $args = null, $instance ) {
            global $wpdb;
            $args = wp_parse_args( (array)$args, array( 'number' => 3 ) );
            $siteurl = get_option( 'siteurl' );
            $options = get_option( 'wpsc-widget_latest_products' );
            $number  = isset($instance['number']) ? (int)$instance['number'] : 3;
            $image  = isset($instance['image']) ? (bool)$instance['image'] : FALSE;

            if ( isset($instance['width'] ) )
                $width = $instance['width'];

            if ( isset( $instance['height'] ) )
                $height = $instance['height'];

            $latest_products = get_posts( array(
                'post_type'   => 'wpsc-product',
                'numberposts' => $number, 
                'orderby'     => 'post_date',
                'post_parent' => 0,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'order'       => 'ASC'
            ) );
            $output = '';

            $total = count( $latest_products ); 
            $i = 0; 
            if ( count( $latest_products ) > 0 ) {


                $output .= '<div class="grid no-border" ><ul>';     
                foreach ( $latest_products as $latest_product ) {

                    //print_r($latest_product);
                    $i++;
                    if ( !($i%3)) $class = 'last'; else $class = '';
                    $output .= '<li class="item '.$class.' ">';
                    // Thumbnails, if required
                    if ($image) {                   
                        $output .= '<a class="product-image" href="' . wpsc_product_url( $latest_product->ID, null ) . '">';
                        $attached_images = (array)get_posts( array(
                            'post_type'   => 'attachment',
                            'numberposts' => 1,
                            'post_status' => null,
                            'post_parent' => $latest_product->ID,
                            'orderby'     => 'menu_order',
                            'order'       => 'ASC'
                        ) );
                        $attached_image = $attached_images[0]; 
                        if ( $attached_image->ID > 0 )
                                $output .= '<img class="product_image" src="' . wpsc_product_image( $attached_image->ID, $width, $height ) . '" title="' . $latest_product->post_title . '" alt="' . $latest_product->post_title . '" />';
                        else
                            $output .='<img class="no-image product_image" id="product_image_'.wpsc_the_product_id().'" alt="No Image" title="'.wpsc_the_product_title().'" src="'.WPSC_URL.'/wpsc-theme/images/noimage.png" width="' . $width . '" height="' . $height . '" />';

                        $output .= '</a>';

                    }
                    // Link
                    $output .= '<h3 class="product-name"><a href="' . wpsc_product_url( $latest_product->ID, null ) . '" class="wpsc-product-title">'.stripslashes( $latest_product->post_title ).'</a></h3>';



                    $output .= '<p class="product-desc">'. $latest_product->post_content.'</p>';
                    $output .=  '<div class="action">';

                    $output .= '<div class="price-box left">';
                    //$output .= $latest_product->ID;
                    //$output .= wpsc_calculate_price( wpsc_the_product_id(),null,false );
                    $output .= wpsc_currency_display(get_post_meta( $latest_product->ID, '_wpsc_price', true ));
                    $output.= '</div>';

                    $output .= '<a class="button right" href="' . wpsc_product_url( $latest_product->ID, null ) . '"><span>'.__( 'Details', 'wpsc' ).'</span></a>';

                    $output .= '<div class="clear"></div></div>';

                    $output .= '</li>';
                }
                $output .= "</ul></div><div class=\"clear\"></div>";
            }
            echo $output;
        }
```

UPDATE: Fixed this problem. It didn't save because of wrong class name as a parameter.

```
                $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'widget_mz_wpsc_latest_products','description' => __( 'Phomedia Latest Products Widget', 'wpsc' ) );
                $this->WP_Widget( 'wpsc_latest_products', __( 'Phomedia Latest Products', 'wpsc' ), $widget_ops );
```